# Creating history trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, history

I'm trying to write a history trigger but can't get it to work.

here is the code :

```
create or replace
TRIGGER abc BEFORE
    UPDATE ON abc REFERENCING OLD AS oldValue NEW AS newValue
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        INSERT
    INTO history
        (
            id,
            record_id,
            col_name,
            old_val,
            new_val
        )
        VALUES
        (
            MF_SEQ_HISTORY.nextval,
            :oldvalue.id,
            :oldvalue.column_name,
            :oldvalue.object_value,
            :newvalue.object_value
        );
        END;
```

as you can see , i'm trying to save the column name that has been updated ,the value and the new value.

the errors i'm getting is :

```
Error(19,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLDVALUE.COLUMN_NAME'
Error(20,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLDVALUE.OBJECT_VALUE'
Error(21,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEWVALUE.OBJECT_VALUE'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What tool do you use to connect to the DB? This should work with SQL*Plus

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with the code you've supplied. it works. but does table ABC have columns called column_name and object_value? if so, please give the sqlplus output of `DESC ABC`

```
SQL> create table abc (id number, column_name varchar2(30), object_value varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> create table history (id number, record_id number, col_name varchar2(30), old_val varchar2(30), new_val varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> create sequence mf_seq_history start with 1;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace
  2  TRIGGER abc BEFORE
  3      UPDATE ON abc REFERENCING OLD AS oldValue NEW AS newValue
  4      FOR EACH ROW
  5      BEGIN
  6          INSERT
  7      INTO history
  8          (
  9              id,
 10              record_id,
 11              col_name,
 12              old_val,
 13              new_val
 14          )
 15          VALUES
 16          (
 17              MF_SEQ_HISTORY.nextval,
 18              :oldvalue.id,
 19              :oldvalue.column_name,
 20              :oldvalue.object_value,
 21              :newvalue.object_value
 22          );
 23          END;
 24  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into abc values (1, 'COL', 'TEST');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into abc values (1, 'COL2', 'TEST2');

1 row created.

SQL> update abc set object_value ='a';

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from history;

        ID  RECORD_ID COL_NAME
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
OLD_VAL                        NEW_VAL
------------------------------ ------------------------------
         1          1 COL
TEST                           a

         2          1 COL2
TEST2                          a


SQL>
```

Comment: hi thank you for the answer , however it's not what i meant. i want the column name and the object value to be automatically inserted by the column that was updated , if I have 50 columns in ABC , and I update column number 30 I want the column name to be insterted into the history table, I hope it's clear now. Thank you!

Comment: this is not possible. the bind variables are literals and cannot be soft coded like the way you are thinking.

Comment: You need to compare old value and new value in that case for all columns, if there is difference then do the insert.

Comment: I've seen this kind of trigger my self , where it's takes the old values and the old value before the update and insert into a different table,If two columns are updated , then insert 2 records into the history table.

Comment: You can add multiple if conditions for each column, where you can compare old value and new value if differnce is there then add values in log table.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is something you are looking for :- 
[http://birijan.com.np/?q=oracle+trigger+-+column+level+auditing](http://birijan.com.np/?q=oracle%20trigger%20-%20column%20level%20auditing)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to use the supplied functionality for version enabling a table in the Oracle database. Take a look at the workspace manager: DBMS_WM.EnableVersioning.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/workspace-management-9i.php

```
exec dbms_wm.enableversioning('LANDEN','view_wo_overwrite');

insert into landen values (1,'Nederland','The Netherlands','Nederland','NL','NL','NL',sysdate);
update landen set naamnl = 'Holland' where pk = 1;

select pk,naamnl from landen;

1   Holland

select pk,naamnl,retiretime from landen_lt;

1   Nederland   08-11-2012 11:01:14,466296000 +01:00
1   Holland
```